# Is it possible to express an arbitrary tensor contraction in terms of BLAS routines?

Tags: tensor-products

This question sits at an intersection of mathematics and computer science. Basically, I want to express an arbitrary tensor contraction in terms of BLAS routines. That is, only using tensor reshaping, matrix and vector multiplication and such.

For example, contracting tensors with shapes (2,3,4) and (3,4,5) respectively along dimensions with sizes 3 and 4 can be accomplished by reshaping them into matrixes with dimensions (2, 12) and (12, 5) and then performing a matrix multiplication.

However, I struggle to come up with a general algorithm to do that. For example, I can't think of a way to do that when the contracted dimension isn't at either ends of the tensor. Say, performing tensor contraction of tensors with shapes (2,3,4) and (5,4,6) respectively, only using BLAS routines.

Let me know if this question is better suited for cs stackexchange. Thank you :)

Comment: I think this is better suited for scicomp.stackexchange, but I'll try to answer here to the extend of my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

A common approach is to transpose the tensors so that the contraction can be performed by one matrix multiplication. In your example, you can reshape (5,4,6)-shape tensor into a (5,24)-matrix, transpose and then reshape to (4,30).
Transposition of matrices is technically not a part of BLAS, but is available in most implementations.

But matrix reshape and transpose can only implement cyclic transpose of tensors, to do arbitrary tensor transposition you need to make loops of matrix transpositions or use special tensor transpose library. For example, transposing (3,4,5) into (3,5,4) would require a loop over the first index.

You can look at the paper "[Design of a high-performance GEMM-like Tensor-Tensor Multiplication](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.00145)" by Springer and Bientinesi. In addition to designing new procedures, it also describes some approaches to do tensor contraction with matrix procedures.

Comment: thank you for the reply, i'll take a look at that paper :)

do i understand correctly that certain types of tensor reshaping do require to actually manipulate the tensor data around? bc i was approaching this question w/ the assumption that tensor reshaping only involves shuffling the dimensions around, w/o acc manipulating the underlying data, so it only takes effect once we need to read/write a certain entry in that tensor...

Comment: That depends on the terminology. I would use the word "reshape" for the procedures which do not actually move the data and "transpose" for those that do.

Comment: by the way, do you happen to know which approach libraries like numpy/pytorch use for tensor contraction?

Comment: Looking at the source, `numpy.einsum` uses `numpy.tensordot`, which uses the transpose-transpose-multiply approach, see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L1119 .
This is not the whole story, because `numpy.transpose` does not actually copy data, but returns a view, so the copy must happen somewhere in the internals around the `numpy.dot` function, but here Numpy starts being complicated and my knowledge ends.

Comment: Pytorch is complicated from the start, and it seems to also use transpose-transpose-multiply approach in its internals here https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/97891b184c12763f335fbe1ff63fab843edafab5/aten/src/ATen/native/Linear.cpp#L789 , but I am not confident that this function does not have additional optimized variants.